# run python in vscode via keyboard shortcut?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

It shows F5 but how do I do that in mac's keyboard? also when I click manually the 'run' menu, it has a dropdown to select, can I auto run the program when I save a file?

Answer (score 3):

When on a MAC, any shortcut using a function key seems rather useless.

[Jason Murray](https://jasonmurray.org/posts/2020/vscodeplay/) shows on his block nicely how to set an appropriate shortcut.

1. Click on the gear in the lower-left corner of the screen and select Keyboard Shortcuts.
2. Search for "Python: Run Python File in Terminal."
3. Click on the search result and enter a keyboard shortcut sequence. Jason proposes `CTRL+r`, and I found that `control+r` also works well on macOS

Comment: "When on a MAC, any shortcut using a function key seems rather useless.". Why?

Comment: That may be putting it a little too hard. But I always have trouble using the function keys on a Mac as they are not depicted on the keyboard, which ends up with me trying to find the right key by trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Just press Fn + Ctrl + F5 it won't ask you to select. if you press F5 it will ask to select as it includes debug.

Old Version

```
Ctrl + F5 for Win
Fn + Command + F5 on Mac
```

if it doesn't work try this in the new version

```
Command + F5
```

Reference for 
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/27685